# Using list comprehensions to remove a list element by index

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

A table is a list of lists, where the data is set up as follows:

```
data Position = CEO | Manager| Programmer | Intern deriving (Eq, Show)

data Field = EmployeeID Int | T Position | Name String | Salary Int deriving (Eq)

instance Show Field where
    show (EmployeeID k) = show k
    show (T p) = show p
    show (Name s) = s
    show (Salary k) = show k

type Column = Int
type Row = [Field]
type Table = [Row]
```

An example table would look like this:

```
employees = [[EmployeeID 1, Name "Shoo"],
    [EmployeeID 2, Name "Barney"],
    [EmployeeID 3, Name "Brown"],
    [EmployeeID 4, Name "Gold"],
    [EmployeeID 5, Name "Sky"]]
```

How would I go about using a list comprehension to create a function that removes a column from the table? I do not know how to operate on lists of lists. I need to have the function have a type of `delete :: Column -> Row -> Row`

Comment: Shouldn't that be Column -> Table -> Table? Otherwise you don't need to worry about nested lists.

Comment: No, the professor of this class has a tenancy to make things difficult

Comment: If having this function is part of the assignment, your professor probably intends you to implement the function for tables by mapping the function for rows. You can do that using list comprehension..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were to implement this without list comprehensions, I'd use [map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3amap) and [filter](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3afilter).

Happily, you [can easily do both of those with list comprehensions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/List_processing#List_comprehensions).

I'm going to avoid using your code, but as an example, suppose I had the list of lists:

```
nameSets = [[ "dave", "john", "steve"]
           ,[ "mary", "beth", "joan" ]
           ,[ "daren", "edward" ]
           ,[ "riley"]
           ]
```

And I wanted to get excited versions of all the lists with three elements:

```
[ [ name ++ "!" | name <- nameSet ] | nameSet <- nameSets, length nameSet == 3 ]
-- [[ "dave!", "john!", "steve!"]
-- ,[ "mary!", "beth!", "joan!" ]
-- ]
```

---

*Edit*: Just noticed that your column is specified by index.  In that case, a [zip](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3azip) is useful, which can also be done with list comprehensions, but a language extension is needed.

In a source file, put `{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}` at the top to do zips in list comprehensions.

Here's how they work:

```
% ghci -XParallelListComp
ghci> [ (x,y) | x <- "abcdef" | y <- [0..5] ]
[('a',0),('b',1),('c',2),('d',3),('e',4),('f',5)]
```

Or, without the extension

```
% ghci
ghci> [ (x,y) | (x,y) <- zip "abcdef" [0..5] ]
[('a',0),('b',1),('c',2),('d',3),('e',4),('f',5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension does not work very well for removing by index, but here's a try (homework adjusted):

```
deleteAt :: Column -> Row -> Row
deleteAt n r = [e|(i,e) <- zip (a list of all indexes) r, test i] where
  test i = (True if index i should be kept and False otherwise)
```

If you want to make a list comprehension that operates on lists of lists, you can just nest the comprehensions:

```
operate :: Table -> Table
operate t = [[myFunction field|field <- row, myPredicate field]| row <- t]

myFunction :: Field -> Field
myPredicate :: Field -> Bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this isn't an answer since you requested using list comprehensions. But I think list comprehensions are quite ill-suited to this task.  You only need `take` and `drop`.

```
ghci> take 2 [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2]
ghci> drop 2 [1,2,3,4,5]
[3,4,5]
```

To delete an element at index *i*, append together the first *i* elements and the list with the first *i+1* elements dropped.